# Can "Monday", "Tuesday" be plural like "Mondays" or "Tuesdays"?

Tags: word-usage, singular-vs-plural

Which of the following sentences are correct?

1. From now on, the biochemistry lecture classes on Mondays at 10.30 a.m. will be held on Sundays at 11.30 a.m instead.
2. From now on, the biochemistry lecture classes on Monday at 10.30 a.m. will be held on Sunday at 11.30 a.m instead.
3. From now on, the biochemistry lecture class on Monday at 10.30 a.m. will be held on Sunday at 11.30 a.m instead.
4. From now on, the biochemistry lecture class on Mondays at 10.30 a.m. will be held on Sundays at 11.30 a.m instead.

Comment: Both forms are used. *Mondays* is not incorrect.

Comment: Whilst I agree that none of your examples are 'incorrect', and are perfectly clear in meaning, my way of saying the same thing would be: From now on the 10.30am-Monday class will be held on Sundays at 11.30am instead.

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of all of the examples you've given can be easily understood, but perhaps the best (that is, that with the least ambiguity) is

> From now on, the biochemistry lecture class on Mondays at 10.30 a.m. will be held on Sundays at 11.30 a.m instead.

To answer your question, days of the week can be [pluralized](http://www.accu-assist.com/grammar-tips-archive/01-17-07_GrammarTip_apostrophes5.htm) as you've done in your examples.

> - He'll never run the marathon, not in a month of [Sundays](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+month+of+Sundays).
> - [Mondays](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2011/07/25/mondays-are-more-depressing_n_908491.html) Are More Depressing Than We Thought, Says Study
> - French [Tuesdays](https://frenchtuesdays.com/) provides the Y generation with a fun, empowering social event...
> - Wednesdays are known in the US as "hump day".