# Should I say on Fridays or on Friday?

Tags: word-choice

If someone asks a question like:

> When did you stay here?

Would it be right to say "on Fridays"? Or "on Friday"?

Comment: Related (not duplicate): *[Can “Monday”, “Tuesday” be plural like “Mondays” or “Tuesdays”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15341)*

Comment: The plural usage in, say, *I go to work on Saturdays* unambiguously states that you *always* (or at least, *regularly*) work on that day. The singular *could* be used with the same meaning, but in some contexts it might just mean you (will) work on *one specific Saturday* (usually, the next one after time of speaking).

Answer (score 4):

"On Friday" has a different meaning from "On Fridays." "On Friday" in response to the question, "When did you stay here?" means "I stayed here last Friday" (or a particular Friday gleaned from the context of the question.) "On Fridays" would indicate a habitual or recurring stay on several Fridays.

Answer (score 4):

Which you use depends on the context.  "On Fridays" means recurring action that occurs regularly on a Friday.  "On Friday" means a single instance that occurred on a single Friday.

In this context you are asking about a past event, "When **did** you stay here?"  So the most reasonable answer of the two given is, "On Friday".

Now, it is possible that you stayed more than one time, on multiple Fridays.  In that case your answer would have to be more specific, something like:

> *On every Friday in May*

or

> *On a couple of Fridays last summer.*