# "on Friday" Or "on Fridays" with a frequency adverb

Tags: singular-vs-plural, periods, frequency

Ive seen both plural and singular period nouns with frequency adverbs, but which one is correct?

1. I **usually** watch a series on **Friday**.
2. I **usually** watch a series on **Fridays**.

Or maybe neither is wrong?

There's a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/82821/19092), but it doesn't exactly imply frequency adverbs.

Comment: 1a - *I usually watch a series on **a** Friday.* They're all fine, and they mean the same thing. Your "usually" forces the "repeatedly" interpretation, but note that (3) *I don't work on Friday* could mean I won't be working *...on the coming Friday*, OR *...on **any** Friday*. But *with* the article, or the plural form, both imply ***any*** Friday without ambiguity.

Comment: I think you mean that you watch an episode, not a (whole) series.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. So the first instance mentioned in the question _without any article_ has an ambiguity that whether implies on a repeated action or just one time occurring action, if we remove **usually**? (I watch a series on **Friday**). Is the previous sentence grammatically wrong, without an article for Friday?

Comment: Yes - *if you remove the word **usually***. Except for the "only on the **coming** Friday" sense we'd more likely use explicit future *I **will** watch a series on Friday*.

Comment: @alphabet Yes, you're probably right. But maybe It's a miniseries, Who knows? :D